# Scala - Can implicitNotFound annotation be applied at the method level?

Tags: scala, annotations, implicit

I have a method that takes type parameters with an implicit view bounds on them. Can I use the @implicitNotFound annotation to give nicer compiler errors when the method is called with invalid data types?

The documentation for the method is useless and even the source code doesn't help, and all the examples of use online are at the trait or class level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot directly do that. As you’ve noticed, `@implicitNotFound` annotates traits or classes. You could, however, make a special implicit type just for that method and annotate it if you really wanted to have a custom message.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Seems a bit strange why it can only be applied at the type level - surely if methods take type parameters as well this should be allowed?