# Type-safe Builder: How to set compiler error message

Tags: scala

I am using phantom types in the type-safe builder pattern to ensure methods are called only once as in the following code sample

```
  sealed trait TBoolean
  sealed trait TTrue extends TBoolean
  sealed trait TFalse extends TBoolean

  class Builder[MethodCalled <: TBoolean] private() {

    def foo()(implicit ev: MethodCalled =:= TFalse): Builder[TTrue] = {
      new Builder[TTrue]
    }
  }

  object Builder {
    def apply() = new Builder[TFalse]()
  }
```

`Builder().foo().foo()` does not work as required, however I would like to set the error message to something user-readable. At the moment the message is

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - not enough arguments for method foo: (implicit ev: =:=[W.TTrue,W.TFalse])W.Builder[W.TTrue]. Unspecified value parameter ev.
>   - Cannot prove that W.TTrue =:= W.TFalse.
>   - Cannot prove that W.TTrue =:= W.TFalse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the type parameters here is a bit of an overkill. Better just return a less capable type from the `foo` method:

```
object Builder {
  trait CanFoo { def foo() : Builder }
  def apply(): Builder with CanFoo = new Builder with CanFoo {
    def foo() = new Builder {}
  }
}
trait Builder

Builder().foo().foo() // value foo is not a member of Builder
```

---

There is an annotation `implicitNotFound` which [can be used](http://suereth.blogspot.co.at/2011/03/annotate-your-type-classes.html) to customise the error messages, but it needs to be defined with the type that is sought (`=:=`) not with the use site (`foo`), [so that is a pretty useless construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840115/scala-can-implicitnotfound-annotation-be-applied-at-the-method-level)...

...unless you create your own replacement for `=:=`:

```
import annotation.implicitNotFound

object Called {
  implicit def same[A]: Called[A, A] = instance.asInstanceOf[Called[A, A]]
  private object instance extends Called[Any,Any]
}
@implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot call this method twice") sealed trait Called[A, B]

class Builder[Foo <: TBoolean] private() {
  def foo()(implicit ev: Called[Foo, TFalse]): Builder[TTrue] = {
    new Builder[TTrue]
  }
}
object Builder {
  def apply() = new Builder[TFalse]()
}

Builder().foo().foo()  // -> "error: Cannot call this method twice"
```

Comment: It may be prudent to call the trait `NotCalled` rather than `Called`. Otherwise, great post +1.

Comment: It represents the method having been called and hence not eligible for being called again. The name seems appropriate to me.

Comment: or use a type alias `type NotCalled[A] = Called[A, TFalse]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! See my other post on why I wanna use type parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283938/type-safe-builder-how-to-combine-phantom-types/14285948#14285948

Answer (score 2):

You can't customize error messages, but you *can* customize your trait names.  I'd call them `Built` and `Unbuilt` or something like that.  Then you can warn users of the library or whatever that you'll get a hairy-looking error message, but they really only need to spot something that looks like `Cannot prove that Built =:= Unbuilt`.